# Amazon S3 hosted websites accessing data which are in a different bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, website-hosting

I'm trying to host a website on S3, I need to know if the website can access data in another bucket? for example images or locations if they're not in the website's bucket

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the data public, it can definitely be accessed from other buckets or from anywhere else.
Just be sure to mark the option "static website hosting" or something like that in AWS S3 panel.

If you look at the HTML of many popular websites, you'll see that they call images and other assets from S3 buckets.